# Why do I have (master|MERGING) on the command line and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: git

For some reason whenever I go to my command line this is what I see next to my cwd:

[image]

I few days back I got an error message that said I had a merge conflict. I didn't know what this meant so I stopped trying to commit. Now whenever I go onto the git terminal I see `(master|MERGING)`. And whenever I try to commit (even when it's not on the same remote) I get a lengthy error:

[image]

It says to fix the error but I'm not sure how to go about that. What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: See also [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/456814).

Comment: See also [Pro Git: 3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging - Basic Merge Conflicts](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts).

Comment: you have merge conflicts needs resolving prior to merge, look at this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35020326/4356754

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Try running `git reset --merge` or `git merge --abort` (they are equivalent)

Comment: When I did `git reset --merge` it said `Deletion of directory gitproject failed. Should I try again? (y/n)`

Comment: @user2030677 - Can you give output of `git status`?

Comment: @user2030677 did you try `git merge --abort`?

Comment: OP, please consider that these commands will undo any changes you might have done to the files since the merge conflict error appeared.

Comment: @manojlds `git status` shows me a whole bunch of directories and files that aren't even in `gitproject`..

Comment: @Cupcake I didn't try that yet.

Comment: @manojlds Actually, `git status` shows me untracked files both in and outside `gitproject`.

Comment: -1 (for now): an answer that destructively removes any of the OP's data without any warning is a worse answer than "turn off your computer and you won't get any more messages". I understand that the OP is working in a newly created repository. Others reading this may not.

Comment: @hvd to be fair, the OP already screwed himself over when he failed to resolve a merge in the middle of conflicts because he didn't understand what merge conflicts are.